# How to check if element is already loaded via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to check if element is already loaded.

HTML

```
<button>load</button>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('click','button',function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'additional.html',
        context: document.body,
    }).done(function(html) {
        $('body').append(html);
    });
});
//My incorrect suggestion
if ($('input').is(':visible')) {
    alert('I see loaded element!');
}
```

I could move alert to `.done()` block, **but** I am not allowed to change it.
So what event listener should I use for `if` statement in order to show `alert` when element appears?

Comment: code logic inside `done()` callback

Comment: @A.Wolff I'm writing userscript. I am not allowed to change done().

Comment: So, the only solution I see now is wrapping if statemnt in loop with timeout.

Comment: No, use global ajax method instead, see: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

Comment: @A.Wolff I'll explain more specific. Do you know Google Map Maker? It allows to edit Google Maps by yourself. When I create an object on a map, there are input-fields loading in the left sidebar. So I have to to something when that inputs appear.

Comment: and when you create an object on map, is an ajax request send? If ya, you can still use global ajax method

Comment: @A.Wolff .ajaxComplete() doesn't work. How can I check if there is an ajax request?

Comment: when you add a map's object, check your network tab. I don't know Google Map Maker unfortunately. Now i'm confused to find any relation with your question and your comments... You talk about an ajax request in your question, so what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
$('body').bind("loaded", function () {
    alert('I see loaded element!');
});

$(document).on('click','button',function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'additional.html',
    context: document.body,
  }).done(function(html) {
    $('body').append(html);
    $('body').trigger("loaded");
  });
});
```

Or you can set jquery ajax to be sync, because it async as default.